# Missing KB from Default 1MB stack

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, stack, masm

Pretty novice in assembly language, I wanted to test when a stackoverflow exception would happen with the following code:

```
    .386
    .model flat, stdcall
    .stack 4096 ; irrelevant for 32bit 

ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD
    .code
main PROC

    mov ecx, (1024*1024/4) ; 1 048 576 - bytes is 1MB
    mov eax, -1
    ;ESP start: ...
    L1: push eax
    ;ESP end:   ; stackOverflow Exception
    loop L1

    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP

END main
```

The difference between the ESP values at the beginning and on hitting the stackoverflow exception should have been very close to the 1MB.
However, after some 4 odd tests:

```
  0015FF54 ESP before loop
- 00063000 ESP on exception
=    FCF54 = 1,036,116 bytes

  003FF8F0 ESP before loop
- 00303000 ESP on exception
=    FC8F0 = 1,034,480 bytes

  0034F9EC ESP before loop
- 00253000 ESP on exception
=    FC9EC = 1,034,732 bytes

  0043FDD8 ESP before loop
- 00343000 ESP on exception
=    FCDD8 = 1,035,736 bytes
```

Where is there this roughly 14KB discrepancy?

EDIT:
Running in VS 2019 debugger on 64bit Windows 7.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?  It is likely that the kernel puts some data on the stack (e.g. command line arguments, environment variables) for use by your program.  That may account for the extra stack space.

Comment: thanks for the input. Edited the question. I knew that some overhead is to be expected, but 14KB seemed excessive, especially at the root of the program.

Comment: Unfortunately I am entirely unfamiliar with Windows. Another issue seems to be that the stack ends `0x3000` bytes (12 kB) short of a “round” boundary.  Perhaps Windows reserves some pages at the bottom of the stack as a sentinel to avoid collisions with other data?

Comment: Windows reserves some space at the bottom of the stack - otherwise there would be no stack available to handle the StackOverflow exception itself!